# Returning to my if statement

Tags: python-3.x

This is my first time on this site and am new to programming. I need the user to be able to input another word if they say "y". As of now the program sends them back to the         ***while***   statements. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
print('Welcome to Word Madness!!')

vowels = list('aeioyu')

consonants = list('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz')

wordCount = 0

complete = False

while not complete:
    mode = input('Would you like to type Vowels, Consonants, or Quit?: ').lower().strip()
    print('You chose to enter: ',str(mode))

#When user chooses to quit program will system exit

    if mode == 'quit':
        print('Sorry to see you go! Come back to Word Madness soon!')
        import sys
        sys.exit(0)

#If vowels are selected then they will be counted

    if mode == 'vowels':
        word = input('Please enter your word!')
        number_of_vowels = sum(word.count(i) for i in vowels)
        print('Your word was : ',word,'Your Vowel count was: ',number_of_vowels)
        wordCount = wordCount + 1
        choice = input('Do you have another word? Y/N: ').lower().strip()

        if choice == 'n':
            averageV = int(number_of_vowels // wordCount)
            print('Your average number of Vowels was: ',averageV)
            print('Thank you for using Word Madness!')
            complete = True

        else:
            mode = 'vowels'

#If consonants are selected then they will be counted

    elif mode == 'consonants':
        word = input('Please enter your word!')
        number_of_consonants = sum(word.count(i) for i in consonants)
        print('Your word was : ',word,'Your Consonant count was: ',number_of_consonants)
        wordCount = wordCount + 1
        choice = input('Do you have another word? Y/N: ').lower().strip()

        if choice =='n':
            averageC = int(number_of_consonants // wordCount)
            print('Your average number of Consonants was: ',averageC)
            print('Thank you for using Word Madness!')
            complete = True
#If user has no more words to enter then they are given an average

         else:
            mode == 'consonants'

    else:
        print('ERROR! INVALID INPUT DETECTED!')
```

Comment: The code seems fine to me. Can you clarify what you are looking for the code to do instead?

Comment: Is there a question here? There is no clear problem statement whatsoever.

Comment: I apologize. The problem is that when the user inputs "y", instead of going back to the if mode == x, it is going back to the while not complete. Wanted to know if there was a way for the user's input to go back to when they inputted vowel or consonant instead of the program starting over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question and the comment, I assume that you want to ask

> mode = input('Would you like to type Vowels, Consonants, or Quit?: ').lower().strip()

only once.  If that is the case, you can move that statement just above the while loop. 
Or also, you can give an option whether user really wants to specify the mode again.

Comment: @DarrellHooper If this was the answer  you were expecting, can you mark it as answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,for what I understood you don't know how to go back in the code. For this you should learn how to use `functions` in Python. 
What is a function?

A function is a block of organized, reusable code that is used to perform a single, related action. Functions provide better modularity for your application and a high degree of code reusing. (Definition taken from internet)

So I would suggest you to find more about functions, because it's very useful.
After learning functions you should add that:

After every

```
 if choice =='n':
        averageC = int(number_of_consonants // wordCount)
        print('Your average number of Consonants was: ',averageC)
        print('Thank you for using Word Madness!')
        complete = True
```

Add

```
elif choice == 'n':
        function()
```

Function() --> Calling the main function.

Comment: Thanks! Will make sure to make that I priority in my learning!